# why I dont have Audit option in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, audit

I am using SQL server 2008 but still in my sql server management studio I dont have `audit` option under the `Security` menu though `login, Server Rols, Credentials` are there.Why?
[alt text http://www.bradmcgehee.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/clip_image004_thumb.gif](http://www.bradmcgehee.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/clip_image004_thumb.gif)

Comment: AH, you aren ot using SQL Server 2008. As per Brian you are running a prerelease version that you never updated to the "real" one. And likely - you also dont run an enterprise version.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm.... your server version is 10.0.1442, which is a pre-RTM build version.  Are you running a CTP version of SQL Server.  SQL Server 2008 RTM was build 10.0.1600.  My guess is that you have a pre-release version of SQL that did not yet include that feature.  I would install a post-release version, preferably at least SQL Server 2008 + SP1 (10.0.2531).  I think you find the feature then.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is built on top of Extended Events and audits server and database events and groups of events. Database level auditing is supported only by the Enterprise and Developer editions. In SQL Server 2012, all editions support server level audits